# Returning items from a function in python

Tags: python, function, return

How can I return the commented out line below the print statement at the end of this function?  Also, when I run the function with the return un-commented, I get one result, but when I run the function with the return commented, I get 7 results and I'm not sure why this is happening.

What I would like to do is call track['name'] after I call the function.  When I do, I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spot.py", line 25, in 
    track['name']
NameError: name 'track' is not defined

```
import requests
import json

message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind".split()
size = len(message)

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        track_title = ' '.join(w)
        num_words_removed = len(words) - len(w)
        new_message_length =  size - num_words_removed
        new_message = message[new_message_length:size]

        for track in json_dict["tracks"]:
            if track["name"].lower() == track_title.lower():
                print track["name"], " | ", track["href"], " | ", track_title, " | ", num_words_removed
                #return track["name"], track["href"], track_title, num_words_removed


decrementList(message)
```

Comment: Do you want to return all `track`s or only one or one after another (as generator)?

Comment: only one is fine, i just need the first match.

Comment: What do you mean by "call track['name']"?

Answer (score 1):

A return statement causes the function to stop executing and return the value you have specified, whereas with a print statement it just causes something to be output to the terminal, and the function continues to execute.

In order to use the value that is returned from the function, you must do something with it, like assign it to a variable.  For example:

```
track = decrementList(message)
```

but in that case, you would want to return the track:

```
    for track in json_dict["tracks"]:
        if track["name"].lower() == track_title.lower():
            return track
```

Comment: okay thanks. any idea how i can make the return work?  when i try and call `track['name']` i get an error

Comment: @Barnaby: I've extended my answer.

Comment: @VaughnCato or do `return track["name"], track["href"], track_title, num_words_removed` and `name, href, title, nwords_removed = decrementList(message)`